# Limiting the choices available when user clicks "Create"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

When a user clicks "Create" from the "View all site content" page, a silverlight dialog box pops up presenting them with choices.  We would like to limit the choices available to them in this dialog box.  Searching google doesn't seem to return the results I am looking for.
Can someone tell me the basics of doing this, or what I should be searching for in order to educate myself as to how this task might be performed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If keeping the Silverlight based dialog is not a requirement, you can develop a custom DelegateControl WebControl which is pinned to the placeholder AdditionalPageHead as described here https://littletalk.wordpress.com/2010/11/18/create-an-additionalpagehead-control-packed-into-a-feature-in-visual-studio-2010/

This control could contain a piece of JavaScript to disable the Silverlight dialog on the  "View all site content" (viewlsts.aspx) page. SharePoint will then automatically fallback to the classic "/_layouts/create.aspx" page.

Within your WebControl you can then use C# server-side code to detect if you are on the create.aspx page and apply custom CSS to hide the lists you don't want your users have them created.

Additionally your WebControl can optionally include C# server-side code to detect if a smart user tried to navigate directly to the "/_layouts/new.aspx" page with certain querystrings to create a list directly and block access to those urls.

I've done something like this a while back to allow only certain audiences to create certain type of lists. Works like a charm.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't any way to accomplish this.  The available list, library, and site types are driven by the features that are turned on.  In addition, many of them are built-in to the foundation (these ones cannot be turned off).  The only thing you could do is add some event receivers to the site to block the creation of certain item types, but it wouldn't remove them from the Create menu.

Comment: Alternatively you could not give them the ability to create anything and create a custom application page or web part that creates certain list/library types programmatically.  Then let them use that instead...

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the available list templates if you create your own web template.

Here is a simple refernce for web templates, that should be enough to get you started
http://www.chakkaradeep.com/post/Web-Templates-in-SharePoint-2010-What-You-Should-Know.aspx

This is the best and most complete reference for web templates that I know of, although it can be a bit too over engineered for an hello world example
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2010/10/14/sharepoint-2010-and-web-templates.aspx